# Hard drive memory exhausted (0 bytes) and system does not startup

Tags: 16.04, nvidia, live-usb, ram, memory-usage

NVIDIA Jetson TX2 has about 29 GB of data all of which was consumed during a build. Now when I am trying to restart, just the Wi-Fi connection pop-up keeps jumping but the system does not startup.
Using UBUNTU 16.04.
What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I simply plugged in a USB drive (just in case).
The USB folder popped up and kept blinking. Between these blinks, I managed to delete some big chunks of data and as I did it, the blinking stopped and I have my baby back!!

## Jetson guys,pls do better on the hard-drive size...PLS!

Comment: In a normal Ubuntu setup with EXT4 filesystem (default), there should be 5% (by default) reserved for root. For exact this situation, any process is running wild and generating a lot of data, than root can login and take care of the garbage. You can trick this clever solution by doing anything as root ... But this isn't a Linux problem anymore -> Work as root only when necessary! See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7950/reserved-space-for-root-on-a-filesystem-why

Comment: Yes, I see about 1.5 GB(5% of 32GB total space on Jetson) is always vacant.